# Updating a single file in a compressed tar

Tags: linux, tar

Given a compressed archive file such as `application.tar.gz` which has a folder `application/x/y/z.jar` among others, I'd like to be able to take my most recent version of `z.jar` and update/refresh the archive with it.

Is there a way to do this other than something like the following?

```
tar -xzf application.tar.gz
cp ~/myupdatedfolder/z.jar application/x/y
tar -czf application application.tar.gz
```

I understand the `-u` switch in tar may be of use to avoid having to untar the whole thing, but I'm unsure how to use it exactly.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Well, I found the answer.

You can't use `tar -u` with a zipped archive.  So the solution I used was the following.  Note that I moved the `z.jar` file to a folder I created in the current directory called `application/x/y` for this purpose.

```
gzip -d application.tar.gz
tar -uf application.tar application/x/y/z.jar
gzip application.tar
```

When I did a `tar -tf application.tar` (after the update, before the gzip) it showed up properly.

Answer (score 10):

If the file you want to update is text file. Then you can use `vim` editor directly to open the tarball that contains the file and open it, just like open folder using vim editor. Then modify the file and save it and quit.

However, if the file is a binary. I have no idea about the solution.

Comment: I tried this but I got as far as editing the file inside the archive, but I was unable to save the modified text file inside the archive because vim kept telling me the archive was already open in another memory buffer.

Answer (score 5):

in my case, I had to delete the file and then add the new file with the following steps:

my tar file

```
file.tar
└── foo.json
└── bar.json
└── dir
    └── zoo.json
```

and I wanted only to modify/update `foo.json` file without extracting and re-creating the whole tar file `file.tar`, Here are the commands:

```
tar -x -f file.tar foo.json # extract only foo.json file to my current location
# now modify the file foo.json as you want ...
tar --delete -f file.tar foo.json # delete the foo.json file from the file.tar
tar -uf file.tar foo.json # add the specific file foo.json to file.tar
```

**compressed file:**

if it is compressed file, like `file.tar.gz`, you will need to extract the tar file from the compressed file (in this example gzip) by using `gunzip file.tar.gz` which will create for you the tar file `file.tar`. then you will be able to do the **above** steps.

at the **end** you should compress the tar file again by using `gzip file.tar` which will create for you compressed file with the name `file.tar.gz`

**sub directories:**

in order to handle sub dirs you will have to keep the same structure also in the file system:

```
tar -x -f file.tar dir/zoo.json
# now modify the file dir/zoo.json as you want ...
tar --delete -f file.tar dir/zoo.json
tar -uf file.tar dir/zoo.json
```

**view the file structure:**

by using the `less` command, you can view the structure of the file:

```
less file.tar

drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2020-10-18 11:43 foo.json
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2020-10-18 11:43 bar.json
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2020-10-18 11:43 dir/zoo.json
```

Comment: I am not sure you can update compressed archives (as you suggested at the end of the comment).

Answer (score -1):

On windows, you can use 7zip to edit the file directly in the archive. Just open the archive in 7zip, navigate to the file and open it. It should open in the default system text editor (or give you an open dialog if there is no/unknown file extension). Make your changes, then save it, and then 7zip will ask you if want to save the changes to the file in the archive, which you would say yes to. Then when you close 7zip, it will ask you again to save changes to the entire archive, which you should also say yes to. The archive modified date should be updated, and you can always open it again in the same manner to check the changes were saved. I know this works with tar.gz and zip archives, but I haven't tried it with others.